# Which I give an apk to a person, what's the difference between the versions that Xamarin creates for distribution?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working with Xamarin Forms and I published the Android app ad-hoc to disc.

What I would like to do is to give the apk to some people to test by uploading it to a web site I have so they can download it.  Here's what was created:

```
com.xx.xx-arm64-v8a.apk
com.xx.xx-armeabi-v7.apk
com.xx.xx-x86_64.apk
com.xx.xx-x86.apk
com.xx.xx.apk
```

My question is twofold. Why does it create four apps and which of those should I give to the person? I assume it's okay to give the last in the list but if that's the case then why are the others created?

I also heard something about a new feature with Android that would allow smaller builds and just  let a person download the build that is needed for their device. Can someone tell me if I could use that with these apks and if so how I would do it.

Thanks

Here are the list of options that I have selected:

[image]

Comment: Now I see **five** apk files instead of **four** as you write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your Android Options, If you enable the `Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI` selection, you will get serveral .apk file. If you want to generate one .apk file, just unselect it like following screenshot.
[image]

If you want to enable the `Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI`selection. you can give the .apk file by Users' device(CPU Architectures).

Xamarin.Android supports the following architectures:

**armeabi** – ARM-based CPUs that support at least the ARMv5TE instruction set. Note that armeabi is not thread-safe and should not be used on multi-CPU devices.
Note

**As of Xamarin.Android 9.2, armeabi is no longer supported.**

**armeabi-v7a** – ARM-based CPUs with hardware floating-point operations and multiple CPU (SMP) devices. Note that armeabi-v7a machine code will not run on ARMv5 devices.

**arm64-v8a** – CPUs based on the 64-bit ARMv8 architecture.

**x86** – CPUs that support the x86 (or IA-32) instruction set. This instruction set is equivalent to that of the Pentium Pro, including MMX, SSE, SSE2, and SSE3 instructions.

**x86_64** CPUs that support the 64-bit x86 (also referred as x64 and AMD64) instruction set.

If you want to know more details about CPU Architectures, you can refer to this thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

while you are creating an apk Please make sure your Architecture should be **armeabi-7a and armeabi-v8a** in **Project Properties** - > **Android Options** -> **Advanced**.

after that Clean Solution.

than Please go for .apk Archive it will create simple **Signed Apk** which you can distribute.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I updated the question with information on the options I selected.  Are you saying there is no need to select all four of them?

Comment: as i already mentioned in my answer only select armeabi-7a and armeabi-v8a in Architecture and Archive it. in your image Please go for 1st and 3rd options. rest are no need to select as it is for simulator.